# flutter windows desktop application working in the development pc but doesn't work correctly when I export release (UI issues)

Tags: windows, flutter, dart, desktop-application

**Expected Result**
[image: Expected Result]

**initial Screen**
[image: beginning Screen]

**after scrolling down the content appears without Sidebar**
[image: after scrolling down the content appears without Sidebar]

here is my flutter doctor -v

```
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.0.1, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.22000.739], locale en-US)
    • Flutter version 3.0.1 at C:\flutter\flutter
    • Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
    • Framework revision fb57da5f94 (7 weeks ago), 2022-05-19 15:50:29 -0700
    • Engine revision caaafc5604
    • Dart version 2.17.1
    • DevTools version 2.12.2

[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 33.0.0)
    • Android SDK at C:\Users\Ahmad Alshohan\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
    • Platform android-33, build-tools 33.0.0
    • Java binary at: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin\java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.12+7-b1504.28-7817840)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[√] Chrome - develop for the web
    • Chrome at C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe

[√] Visual Studio - develop for Windows (Visual Studio Community 2022 17.2.4)
    • Visual Studio at C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community
    • Visual Studio Community 2022 version 17.2.32602.215
    • Windows 10 SDK version 10.0.22621.0

[√] Android Studio (version 2021.2)
    • Android Studio at C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.12+7-b1504.28-7817840)

[√] VS Code (version 1.68.1)
    • VS Code at C:\Users\Ahmad Alshohan\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code
    • Flutter extension version 3.42.0

[√] Connected device (3 available)
    • Windows (desktop) • windows • windows-x64    • Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.22000.739]
    • Chrome (web)      • chrome  • web-javascript • Google Chrome 103.0.5060.114
    • Edge (web)        • edge    • web-javascript • Microsoft Edge 103.0.1264.49

[√] HTTP Host Availability
    • All required HTTP hosts are available

• No issues found!
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Would you please [edit] your question and add a [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so others can find an answer for it? Try to strip down your app to the minimal code as possible. Also, is there any debug/error output?

Comment: thanks, I will add minimal-reproducible-example , there is no error output

Comment: I solved it, The bug in my case was happening only when on a language other than the English language in the locale.  thank you All

Comment: Nice to hear that. You can post an answer for yourself, no problem. It's even recommended so others know this solution easier than looking at the comments.

Comment: okay I did it thank you

Answer (score 1):

this solution works for me, The bug in my case was happening only when on a language other than the English language in the locale